# I can not use my play store app

Tags: google-play-store

I want to log in my play store app but it's not letting me log in instead it's asking me redeem your code:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have internet connection. Such screen appears when there is no internet connectivity. As I can see from the screenshot, that you are connected to a WiFi, make sure internet is available from that source.

I have recreated the similar situation. Connected my device to a WiFi which has no internet connectivity; Opened Play Store and this is what I got.

[image: NoInternet]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

So, just connect to a stable source of internet and you will be good to go :)

Comment: You may want to edit your picture in order to hide your email address.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman yeah, did that :)